# Can't seem to delete old Xubuntu kernels, I'm getting the error that the directory isn't empty or that I don't have permission to delete it

Tags: kernel, delete

I'm new to Linux so I might need some help in ELI5 language. I'm out of disk space. I see lots of old kernels that I don't need anymore, but I can't seem to delete them.

When I try this:

`sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove -y`

I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 107 not upgraded.
```

Many kernels still remain afterwards. When I try to remove them manually, using this command:

`sudo apt-get autoremove linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic`

When I do this manually instead, I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.15.0-41-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 107 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 260814 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for linux-image-5.15.0-41-generic (5.15.0-41.44~20.04.1) ...
rmdir: failed to remove '/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic': Directory not empty
```

I don't think that it is true that the directory is empty though, because just this one specific directory is taking up 1.6gb. [See screenshot of that here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFeMr.png)

Can someone help me figure out how to remove these old kernels? It looks like they are taking up a lot of space, and I only have 2 GB left!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo -i
rm -r /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic
```

command to delete:

```
rm [option] FileOrFolderName
```

Use a recursive option, represented by -r, to remove the directory and its content. The following command shows how to delete Simple-Directory and its content:

```
rm -r Simple-Directory
```

related: [how-to-remove-files-and-folders-using-linux-command-line](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-remove-files-and-folders-using-linux-command-line/)

Comment: Good place to mention that the system can be VERY sensitive to typographical errors, and this is one of those times. Check your spelling and spacing carefully...twice...before hitting `<enter>`.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Comment: @slowsounds good news, can you accept my answer please